# why can i not upgrade a chain runtime as per the Substrate tutorial?

Tags: substrate

I followed the instructions at https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/upgrade-a-chain/ to test out upgrading a chain runtime. When I submitted the setCode transaction I received the following error...

invalid transaction transaction would exhaust the block limits

I understand what the error means. But, I don't understand why the tutorial is failing. Has anyone else been able to get this tutorial working. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just like it told you `transaction would exhaust the block limits`

So there're 2 ways to achieve this.

1. Like 2075 said use `sudoUncheckedWeight`, this will bypass the weight checking
2. Use schedule module, this will schedule the runtime upgrade at a specific block height then execute it
3. Democracy (actually this call the schedule implicitly)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try your upgrade through the UI? If you go through Developer > Sudo and select `sudo - sudoUncheckedWeight` and then `system - setCode` it should work.

Another route would go through Developer > Extrinsics, select your sudo account, then sudo, uncheckedWeight and system, setCode.